Syntactic function of Not

He does not like this.

Here, what's the syntactic function of not?

It's a negating particle. Maybe you could unpack your question a bit to allow a more detailed answer.

@StuartF That does not answer the question. Users who ask about syntactic functions are proper grammarians and what they want to know about is the words structural function within the larger phrase or clause it occurs in. So the answer here can either be Head or Modifier depending on ones take of the grammar. An answer would need to elucidate that.

What do you mean by "syntactic" - Do you mean "its position in the clause"? OED: *syntactic 1.a. Of, relating to, or involving syntax, esp. grammatical syntax. == Syntax: I.1.a. The set of rules and principles in a language according to which words, phrases, and clauses are arranged to create well-formed sentences; (also) the analysis or study of such principles; the branch of grammar concerned with this.

@Greybeard I meant its grammartical function in the sentence.

It would be a pity to lose this interesting question.  Can not it be edited to meet the requirement?  There is a difference of approach between some (most?) dictionaries, which tend to call 'not' an adverb and at least some grammarians, notably CGEL (and, by the way,  grammarians of ancient Greek and Latin, who treat the negative ου/μη or non as  particles.  Logic, also, in effect, also treats it as a particle which negates not the verb but a whole proposition.  Yet the three dictionaries I have seen treat 'not' as an adverb.  Can't the question be adjusted to allow the discussion of this?

@Greybeard Respect the author's use of the term used in The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, please do not edit it out in favour of Greybeard's favourite term!

Yᴏᴜʀ Qᴜᴇꜱᴛɪᴏɴꜱ Aʀᴇ Tᴏᴏ Sʜᴏʀᴛ: please put more effort into composing your questions, as it is unfair to expect others to put more effort into answering than you have put into asking. Tell us what led you to ask the question, such as some confusion or lack of clarity over some particular theory or model, what you think the answer may be, or why you question there even being a clear answer. What research into this matter did you do and where, and what in particular did you find there that seems unclear or conflicting to you? What is your own guess or guesses, and why do you think so?

@Araucaria-Him - "@Greybeard I meant its grammartical [sic] function in the sentence. –
Salim uddin Oct 30 at 13:56" ... Your move...

@Greybeard Yes, he translated from the preferred term  for your elucidation.

According to the Cambridge Grammar of the English Langauge, its syntactic function is to mark negation:

In primary verbal negation the negative marker is associated with a primary verb-form: here do is required if there is no other auxiliary verb.
...
Analytic negation is marked by words whose sole syntactic function is
to mark negation, i.e. not and also no in the use in which it
contrasts with yes, as in answering a question, for example. Synthetic negation is marked by words which have some other function as well. Synthetic verbal negation is marked inflectionally, by negative verb-forms.

(p788, emphasis mine)

+1 for CGEL citation.

In the words of Quirk et al (CoGEL), "not" is a particle, that is, a word that cannot be fitted easily into  any of the usual parts of speech. However, dictionaries usually classify "not" as an adverb (for instance, The Shorter Oxford English Dictionary, OLD, Merriam-Webster).
CoGEL: A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language

Please see this comment.

@tchrist If "not" is to be considered an adverb, that is in its most essential occurence in the sentence, as negating verbs, then in Lawler's example ("Not this August, nor this September"), which he claims as showing another "function", it seems to me that "not" is nothing else again than this same adverb, found this time in an elliptical phrase from which the verb is missing.

Your answer just talks about the part of speech, whereas the OP is asking about the syntactic function (aka 'grammatical relations'). Never the twain shall meet.

Re your comment to @tchrist You don't need verbs to negate noun phrases. Adverbs do this all the time! 'Almost a year', 'quite a mistake', 'nearly an adult'

@Araucaria-Him As a particle, the syntactic function is not a sensible concept; no syntactic function can be made out for the particles in phrasal verbs, for instance. As an adverb, the immediate conclusion is "adverbial" (adverbial of negation). In the end, nothing certain can be said. // I don't know about all cases; in the case of John Lawler's example obvious cases can be constructed ("The people would come back, but not this August.": this is obviously "The people would come back, but they would not come back this August.").  (1/2)

@Araucaria-Him  In e.g. "Not a year went by without ….", I agree that ellipsis of a verb can't be invoked. However, this word now commutes with "all", a determiner, and that tends strongly to confer to "not a" the nature of a determiner; nevertheless, I am not aware of this point of view having been put forward in what I read. (2/2)

Its syntactic function is either a particle of the verb does or a complement of the verb does.
@LPH has mentioned CoGEL says not is a particle, but the book isn't keen to distinguish between the grammatical function and the grammatical category. So they seem to be simply treating not as sort of a minor part of speech. But I believe that the particle is a function, not a category, in H&P's CGEL.
Unfortunately, CGEL seems unclear or undecided about whether to call not a particle or simply a complement.

See DW256's post above.

@Araucaria-Him If it's a marker of negation, it's certainly a dependent. Is it then a complement or an adjunct?

No, I don't think so. Markers of various sorts, just like determiners and pre-nucleuses, are not complements or adjuncts.

@Araucaria-Him Do you happen to know where CGEL says determiners and pre-nucleuses are neither complements nor adjuncts?

You will see here under syntactic functions that Co-ordinate, Marker, Determiner and Subject-Determiner are Dependents which are neither Complements nor Adjuncts. It appears that extranuclear dependents such as Pre-nucleus are in fact Complements, which is news to me.

@Araucaria-Him I think prenucleus what can be either a complement (as in What did you do?) or an adjunct (as in When did you do it?). I don't know who drew that diagram of syntactic functions but I don't think it correctly reflects CGEL.

It was Brett Reynolds with input from GKP.

@Araucaria-Him Maybe they should redraw it, don't you think?

You recognise who Brett Reynolds and Geoffrey K Pullum are?

@Araucaria-Him Sure. But their reputation doesn't make when (as in When do you do it?) a complement, does it?

You need to read their analysis of relative causes (and interrogatives). I thought, from previous questions, you had! [Tl;dr: the Prenucleus wh-phrase gets its semantic identity from the antecedent. The gap in the RC (which is the missing Adjunct or Complement etc)  is co-indexed with the Prenucleus].

However, having said that, it's still not clear to me what the Prenucleus is a Complement of ...

@Araucaria-Him I really don't understand what you're trying to say. Unless you saying that the prenucleus when in When do you do it? is a complement, in which case you need to show me how that's even possible, I don't know how you can defend the diagram, regardless of who drew it.

Well, let's see if I can lead you there. According to CamGEL, what are the two direct constituents of the clause When do you do it?

@Araucaria-Him I don't know where you're going with this. But When and the rest.

a) Which of those constituents is the head? b) Is the other bit an optional modifier?

c) What determines the form and optionality of the pre-nucleus?

@Araucaria-Him a) The head is do you do it. b) When is certainly a modifier because it is not licensed by the the head do you do it. You're suspecting that When is obligatory, and therefore that it cannot be a modifier, that it has to be a complement. But you do know that it is not licensed by the lexical verb do, so you're not 100% sure about it being a complement. Here's what I think: When is obligatory not because it's a complement but because it introduces the interrogative sentence. Note that the final gap in the clause 'you do it ____' is not a complement but a modifier.

You're missing the very basics. All modifiers are BY DEFINITION syntactically optional elements. If it's not optional, it's not a modifier. QED. You need to start there.

@Araucaria-Him It is linguists who came up with the definition of 'modifier'. And they are only human and are not perfect and prone to error. There's no denying that yesterday is a modifier in You did it yesterday. Then how could When in When did you do it? be a complement? And what licenses When? You should ask yourself these questions before jumping to the conclusion. The problem with 'prenucleus' being subsumed under 'complement' is more apparent in the tree diagram of Is he ill? (CGEL p 50), where Is is tagged as a prenucleus (comp?) when it should be the head, shouldn't it?

@Araucaria-Him And according to the wiki diagram, "Nucleus" is a type of "Head". In the above-mentioned tree diagram of Is he ill?, CGEL tags he ill as a Nucleus. Does this mean that In Is he ill?, the small clause he ill is the head that licences the complement/prenucleus Is? Doesn't that fly in the face of CGEL's catenative-auxiliary analysis (See p 1210)? The whole thing is messier than you might realize.

@Araucaria-Him Speaking of "by definition", do you remember our discussion about nominal "by definition" not including a Det (determiner function)? Then, you ignored the definition and claimed that "nominal" can exceptionally include a Det in a fused-head NP. If we're to compare the degree to which the definition is literally applied without exception, "nominal" is much more rigid in not allowing exceptions than "modifier".

You keep making up definitions that aren't definitions and inferring things that haven't been said from the literature. Do you agree that father and brother are different relations?

@Araucaria-Him But at least this time, it is you who made up the definition not in the literature. Obligatoriness is not a definition of a complement in CGEL or in the literature. "The most important property of complements in clause structure is that they require  the presence of an appropriate verb that licenses them." (CGEL) I ask you what licenses When but you don't (and most likely can't) answer the question. Even if When is not a modifier (for it cannot be omitted), it doesn't mean that it is a complement as shown in the wiki diagram, because we don't know what licences it.

@Araucaria-Him And you failed to (or chose not to) address the issue of whether to treat the prenucleus Is in Is he ill? not as a head but as a complement, which suggests to me that you don't know how to address it. Correct me if I'm wrong.

@Araucaria-Him Re "nominal", GKP acknowledges that the term is equivalent to N' in X-bar theory, where NP ➔ (D)N'. So, N' by definition cannot include a determiner (function). Here's an excerpt from Syntax: A Generative Introduction: "We can now straightforwardly account for the one-replacement sentences. One-replacement is a process that targets the N' node: [...] Without the intermediate N' node, we would have no way of accounting for one-replacement or conjunction facts. With N', explaining these sentences is easy, since there is more structure in each phrase."

You dId it again in your very first comment!!!! You write: But at least this time, it is you who made up the definition not in the literature. Obligatoriness is not a definition of a complement in CGEL or in the literature. But I've made no such claim! And you're still confusing form and function (N' and all of that!)

@Araucaria-Him Well, you said "All modifiers are BY DEFINITION syntactically optional elements". You didn't exactly say "Obligatoriness is a definition of a complement", but note that the wiki diagram classifies "prenucleus" as "complement", which classification you don't reject (because authority?). So you're essentially saying that obligatoriness of when makes the prenucleus a complement. // Regardless of this endless back and forth, you still can't (or won't) answer if the prenucleus Is in Is he ill? is a complement or a head. And you won't admit how messy the whole thing is.

@Araucaria-Him For you to admit that it's messy and that the wiki diagram isn't in line with CGEL would be a good starting point for both of us.

@Araucaria-Him You said "And you're still confusing form and function (N' and all of that!)" Does this mean GKP himself is also confusing the two? Or that it's you who are confused.

If someone says that by definition no even numbers over 2 are prime, and that therefore a certain given prime number cannot be even, it is ludicrous to argue that the person who made this observation has made up a definition that all odd numbers are prime. And it's even more absurd to use that to try and make the case that the given prime number is even. I'm giving up
